# Expected value of transformation of exponential PDFs

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, transformation

I have the following: $X$ and $Y$ are exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda$.
They are independent of each other. I also have $U = X+Y$ and $V = X-2Y$.
I am asked to find $E(V|U=1)$.
What I tried was: I found the combined distribution of $U$ and $V$, by finding $f(x,y)$ which is

$f(x,y) = \lambda^{2}\cdot \exp(-\lambda(x+y))$, and since $U = X+Y$ and using the Jacobian for the transformation I got

$f(U,V) = \frac{\lambda^{2}}{3}\exp(-λu)$

also since $U=X+Y$ I can find its distribution function using convolution which came out to:

$f(U) = \lambda^{2}u\cdot exp(-\lambda u)$ so

$f(V|U) = f(U,V)/f(U) =\frac{1}{3u}$

therefore $E(V|U=1)$ is the integral of $\frac{v}{u}\,dv$ from $v=0$ to infinity right? but I get infinity which is not the answer

The correct answer is $-0.5$

Please tell me where I went wrong and if there is an easier way to solve this question.

Comment: Also, for some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: @Mr.GandalfSauron thanks, I will look into it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write out the domain of the pdfs as well. i.e. where is the pdf zero and where is it non-zero?.  The region where it is $0$, you don't need to integrate. It is one theme that I see always among people starting probability theory, that they just blindly do a variable change without worrying about the domain. For example, can $U-V=3Y$ be negative? If so, then you should include that in the joint pdf. Also $2X=2U+V$ must be positive.

So the pdf $f(u,v)=\begin{cases}\frac{1}{3}\lambda^{2}\exp(-\lambda u)\,,\, u>v>-2u,\\0\,,\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Similar to what you have done, you will get $f(V|U=1)(v)=\frac{1}{3u}=\frac{1}{3}\,$ but again, you need to mention the domain .

i.e. you still need to have $1>v>-2$.

So $f(V|U=1)(v)=\frac{1}{3}\,,-2<v<1$ and $0$ elsewhere.

So now compute $\int_{\Bbb{R}}vf(V|U=1)(v)\,dv$ to find the expectation.

i.e.

$$\frac{1}{3}\int_{-2}^{1}\,v\,dv=\frac{-1}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I will do my best to consider the domain in the future!